# Finite difference modified Laplacian matrix of coefficients (Python)

Tags: python-2.7, differential-equations

I am wondering if there is a way to define a function which labels the coefficients of a matrix. E.g., I want to have a function which depends on the coefficients of a 2-d difference equation to then build a matrix out of them.

The above might be unclear so let me explain:

I have a matrix which expresses the eigenvector of the 2-d finite difference Laplacian (with an extra term). I have something like this

```
D*a[i,j]=exp(b*j*I)*a[i+1,j]+exp(-b*j*I)*a[i-1,j]+a[i,j+1]+a[i,j-1]-4*a[i,j]
```

Where `I=sqrt(-1)` and `b=constant`. Sorry about the above formatting, I don't know how to latex type on here.

So i want to build a matrix of the coefficients of `D*a[i,j`], so a NxN matrix where i,j=0,1,..., N-1. For example, to compute the coefficient of a[0,0] I would need to compute `D*a[i,j]` for all `i,j=0,1,...,N-1,` and add the coefficients of the terms with non-zero a[0,0], then do the same for each i and j and form a matrix out of these.

I know there is something called Poly which if you have an expression in terms of x you can acquire the coefficients by using Poly then peeling of the coefficients with coeffs(), but i don't know how to define an expression which spits out a matrix of the form `A=[[a[0,0],a[0,1],...],...,[...,a[N-1,N-1]]`.

I'm relatively new to python, I took a course in my second year of university and I'm now doing a PhD, and haven't used python four about 5 years. Sorry if the above isn't clear, it's hard to explain what I want without knowing all the python terminology.

Cheers.